Fourier Transform of a (angular) double integral
I am a sophomore that has not taken formal Fourier analysis yet. This problem came up in a project I am working on and I am not sure how to do it.
I need an expression for
$$\mathscr{F}\left\{\int_{0}^{\phi}\int_{0}^{\theta} f(\theta', \phi') \, d\theta' \, d\phi')\right\}$$
in terms of
$$\mathscr{F}\left\{f(\theta, \phi)\right\}$$
where theta and phi are angles and thus go from 0 to 2pi. Something like equation 8 of thishttps://www.thefouriertransform.com/transform/integration.php, except the variables are angles. The jacobian is included in the integrand, mostly out of convenience. Here is my approach so far, which mirrors the standard way when these are not angles.
Let
$$f\left(\theta,\ \phi\right)=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\theta}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\phi}}F\left(\omega_{k},\omega_{l}\right)e^{i\left(\omega_{k}\theta+\omega_{l}\phi\right)}d\omega_{l}d\omega_{k}$$
be the inverse fourier transform of f, where F is the fourier transform of f. The integration bounds are a consequence of the context of the problem and aren't really important to this question. omega_k and omega_l correspond to the frequencies of theta and phi respectively. Taking the double integral of both sides, we get
$$\int_{0}^{\phi}\int_{0}^{\theta}f\left(\theta',\phi'\right)d\theta'd\phi'=\frac{1}{\left(2\pi\right)^{2}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\theta}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\phi}}F\left(\omega_{k},\omega_{l}\right)\left(\int_{0}^{\theta}\int_{0}^{\phi}e^{i\left(\omega_{k}\theta'+\omega_{l}\phi'\right)}d\theta'd\phi'\right)d\omega_{l}d\omega_{k}$$
evaluating the integral of the exponentials, we obtain
$$-\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\theta}}\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\phi}}\frac{F\left(\omega_{k},\omega_{l}\right)}{\omega_{l}\omega_{k}}\left(e^{i\omega_{k}\theta}-1\right)\left(e^{i\omega_{l}\phi}-1\right)d\omega_{l}d\omega_{k}$$
dealing with the inner omega_phi integral first,
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\phi}}\frac{F\left(\omega_{k},\omega_{l}\right)}{\omega_{l}}\left(e^{i\omega_{l}\phi}-1\right)d\omega_{l}$$
we can split this up into two integrals and take the limit as r goes to 0:
$$\int_{r}^{\frac{2\pi}{\Delta\phi}}\frac{F\left(\omega_{k},\omega_{l}\right)}{\omega_{l}}\left(e^{i\omega_{l}\phi}-1\right)d\omega_{l}+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}F\left(\omega_{k},re^{i\alpha}\right)\left(e^{ire^{i\alpha}\phi}-1\right)d\omega_{k}$$
here, I get kind of stuck. I don't even know if this approach will result in the expression I want. Any and all help is appreciated!
